# Показать содержимое страницы поддомена sub.example.com подставив IP-адрес

Tags: ip, dns

Есть домен example.com с настроенной на стороне регистратора единственной А-записью '@' -> 123.123.123.123.

Можно ли вывести/отобразить содержимое любой страницы поддомена sub.example.com, если А-запись поддомена sub на регистраторе не настроена, но сервер этот поддомен обрабатывает по IP-адресу 123.123.123.123? Как это сделать?

Comment: Прописать себе в etc/hosts

Comment: И что б для вас не стало сюрпризом, ваш сервер скорее всего обрабатывает любой домен по IP, хоть google.com